# How do I predict a discrete valued target variable with RF?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest

I have a target variable with discrete values (13 different values in total). When I  give that as input to RandomForestClassifier, it gives error that input as continuous. And if I give it to regressor it predicts a value between the discrete values. How can I treat this problem?
[image]
These are the only values , the prediction should also be within these values. But rf regressor predicts for example 54.8 , which is not acceptable.

```
df_new[['PSRO','CRP0_VDDN','EYE_WIDTH']].head()
   PSRO  CRP0_VDDN  EYE_WIDTH
0  8.299        1.2       54.6
1  8.299        1.2       66.3
2  8.299        1.2       58.5
3  8.299        1.2       58.5
4  8.299        1.2       62.4
```

Here you can see EYE_WIDTH has only 54.6,66.3 ,58.5 and 62.4 as output. There is no possibility of getting any other values. But the random forest regressor predicts different values

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Is this a multiclass classification problem, or regression? What do the variable levels mean?

Comment: Added output values

Comment: Your target variable `EYE_WIDTH` is in fact a continuous variable, not a categorical. So trying to predict it is a ***regression*** problem (so use RandomForestRegressor, or linear regression, not RandomForestClassifier). *"These are the only values , the prediction should also be within these values. But RF regressor predicts for example 54.8 , which is not acceptable."* That's simply a wrong statement. Please read what regression is.

Comment: But if you really wanted to round the (continuous-valued) output of the regressor to the nearest of the 13 values seen in the input (which you really shouldn't do), you can easily do that in code. But you shouldn't, in general.

Comment: Yes I understand your statement and I am aware of that but this problem is an industrial problem and the Eye_widths other than these values doesn't exist at all.

Comment: Then either a) write a couple of lines of code to round the output of the regressor to the nearest of the 13 values or b) use a classifier, and treat this as 13-class classification. a) is trivial. b) might be a little more accurate. Just start with a). That's your solution.

Comment: This is a duplicate of many posts such as [Prediction of a discrete numerical target. Multiclass Classifier or Regressor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60397041/prediction-of-a-discrete-numerical-target-multiclass-classifier-or-regressor)?. Also, if the question was about statistical end of ML (this one isn't), then see [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/)